# 3-Point Amplitude with Complex Momenta

Tags: quantum-field-theory, scattering, spinors, correlation-functions, helicity

The following is from Schwartz's *Quantum Field Theory and the Standard Model*.

> Next, consider the MHV amplitude. Again, there are only two possibilities allowed by little-group scaling. Since $\frac{\langle 12 \rangle\langle 23 \rangle\langle 31 \rangle}{\langle 12 \rangle^4}$ diverges in the limit of real momenta, the only possibility is
> $$\mathcal{M}(1^{a+}2^{b+}3^{c-}) = C^{abc}\frac{[12]^3}{[13][32]}  \tag{27.93}.$$
> Similarly,
> $$\mathcal{M}(1^{a-}2^{b-}3^{c+}) = C^{abc}\frac{\langle 12\rangle^3}{\langle 13\rangle\langle 32\rangle}  \tag{27.94}.$$
>
> Now, we are calculating the amplitude for identical particles, which must be bosons since they have spin 1. Thus, the answer must be symmetric under interchange of two particles. This is true even for the crossed processes with $3 \leftrightarrow 1$. But the spinor products in this formula are totally antisymmetric. Thus, $C^{abc}$ must be totally antisymmetric under the interchange of any two indices.

First, I suspect there should be a minus sign in (27.94) as we parity conjugate (27.93). But this is not super important.

What I do not understand is the statement that *the spinor products in this formula are totally antisymmetric*.

I can see that we could define, e.g., $\mathcal{M}(3^{c+}1^{a-}2^{b-}) \equiv D^{cab}\frac{\langle 12\rangle^3}{\langle 13\rangle\langle 32\rangle}$ and then derive $D^{cab} = C^{abc}$. But a priori, there is no reason to believe that $C^{cab} = D^{cab}$ is *necessarily* true. (It reminds of $f^{abc}$ in group theory, which can be *made* totally antisymmetric with the right *choice* of basis.)

Am I missing anything?